# nginx proxy_pass solution needed

Tags: nginx

Im trying to achieve the follwoing -

While browsing to my nginx web-server with the following url - `http://server/?device=10.10.21.102`
I want `proxy_pass=http://10.10.21.102` to be set and get the content of `10.10.21.102`.

I've managed work it out with $arg_device but when destination page has images it breaks -

`[09/Mar/2014:22:08:22 +0200] "GET /welcome.png HTTP/1.1" 500 594 "http://server/?device=10.10.21.102/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.3; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C)" "-"`

When I access `http://server/?device=10.10.21.102/welcome.png` - I can see the image.

What would be the easiest way to solve this so css,js,images will be called as:
`GET /?device=10.10.21.102/welcome.png`
and not just
`"GET /welcome.png`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this, with nginx_substitutions_filter module (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubsModule)

It's very easily done.